# Google Cloud Datastore: lookup and update in one transaction

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sdk

I'm following the Cloud Datastore sample from the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries) as well as the [Github](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/tree/master/samples) sample, following the tasks sample. I'm trying to make a single function call, and mark a task as done by looking it up by the description.

```
function markDoneByDesc(queryString) {
  const query = datastore
    .createQuery('Task')
    .filter('description', '=', queryString);
  var taskKeyId;

  datastore
  .runQuery(query)
  .then(results => {
    const tasks = results[0];

    console.log('Task found:', tasks[0]);
    // I realize there might be multiple tasks with the same desc,
    // but I want to update just one for now
    taskKeyId = tasks[0][datastore.KEY].id;
    console.log('Saving the task Key ID', taskKeyId);
    return taskKeyId;
  })
  .then((taskKeyId) => {
    console.log('Calling markDone with task Key ID', taskKeyId);
    markDone(taskKeyId); // From the original function in the sample
    console.log('Updated task');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
}
```

Right now, the update doesn't happen :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, thanks to [@callmehiphop](https://github.com/callmehiphop)'s help!

Looks like I need to convert the `taskKeyId` that is returned in the datastore query into an integer, and then pass it to the `markDone()` function. Otherwise it is passed as a string and the lookup by that ID Key fails.

Here's what the correct code should look like (note the `parseInt()` in the first return statement):

```
function markDoneByDesc(queryString) {
  const query = datastore
    .createQuery('Task')
    .filter('description', '=', queryString);
  var taskKeyId;

  datastore
  .runQuery(query)
  .then(results => {
    const tasks = results[0];

    console.log('Task found:', tasks[0]);
    // I realize there might be multiple tasks with the same desc,
    // but I want to update just one for now
    taskKeyId = tasks[0][datastore.KEY].id;
    console.log('Saving the task Key ID', taskKeyId);
    return parseInt(taskKeyId,10);
  })
  .then((taskKeyId) => {
    console.log('Calling markDone with task Key ID', taskKeyId);
    markDone(taskKeyId); // From the original function in the sample
    console.log('Updated task');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
}
```